# Вопрос по загрузке 3d объекта в mounted vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js

Я не могу понять почему в `load` объект с данными `animated = undefined`.
Я так же пытался реализовать функции `init` и `animate` в `methods` и исполнять их в `load`, но они так же были `undefined`. Задача заключается в том, что когда экземпляр готов, я загружаю мой 3d объект и добавляю его на сцену. После чего анимирую его и меняю флаг `animated` на `true`. В чем заключается проблема? Снизу в коде я закомментировал когда `animated = false` (то, что мне нужно), а когда `undefined`.
И ещё: 3д объект находится в папке **public**.

Код:

```js
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
   
  },
  data() {
    return {
      animated: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let loader = new GLTFLoader();
    
    console.log(this.animated) //false

    loader.load(
    '/threeAssets/obj.gltf',
    function (gltf) {
      gltf.scene.traverse(function (child) {
        if (child.isMesh) {
          object = child;
        }
      })
      console.log(this.animated) //undefined
      init();
      animate();
    });

    function init() {
      ...
    }

    function animate() {
      ...
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
function (gltf) {
  gltf.scene.traverse(function (child) {
    if (child.isMesh) {
      object = child;
    }
  })
  console.log(this.animated) //undefined
  init();
  animate();
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Да, это помогло, спасибо, но WebStorm почему-то все равно подсвечивает его "Element is not exported'.. Можно узнать, что мы изменили, добавив bind(this) и почему не работало до него?

Comment: ну вы передаете функцию вторым аргументом в метод load. Там она вызывается в контексте объекта loader и this указывает на него. bind привязывает к функции текущий контекст

Comment: @Никита чтобы контекст так не привязывать постоянно используйте стрелочные функции за место обычных и всё будет работать